# mysqldump fails if pager set in [client] config section

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

I have this in my `my.cnf`:

```
[client]
pager = 'less -SRXF'
```

Which helps using [mycli](http://mycli.net/). However I've noticed that this causes `mysqldump` to fail `mysqldump: unknown variable 'pager=less -SRXF`

I've tried adding a `[mysqldump]` section without `pager`, or with `pager =` or with `pager = ''` or with `skip-pager` or with `no-pager` to overwrite the `pager` setting (as [described in the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/#mycnf-hierarchy)) but none of that changes the error.

Interestingly:

```
$ my_print_defaults mysqldump
--quick
--quote-names
--max_allowed_packet=16M
```

(I've also tried solving this from the other end, using `[mycli]` or `[mysql]` instead of `[client]` but that does not seem to be read by the mycli program.)

I'm on MariaDB 10.0.32

Comment: You can't add options to `[client]` that aren't compatible with *all* client utilities.

Comment: Right. I'll work on mycli to implement a custom section then. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like the best plan.  A custom section should automatically not interfere with anything else.

Comment: If that fails, file a bug report with bugs.mysql.com. (and/or the MariaDB equivalent in Jira.)